# Problem opening one question on SE Earth Science

Tags: support, images, browsers

I don't know if I should be asking this here or elsewhere but I have an issue opening one question on SE Earth Science.

Yesterday, before an answer was posted to the question there was no issue. Today I tried to open the question to read the answer and my computer either freezes or crashes. Here's the question

[Why do the dry and moist adiabatic lapse rates converge with height?](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/4965/why-do-the-dry-and-moist-adiabatic-lapse-rates-converge-with-height)

I have no problem opening other questions on that site or other SE sites.

Comment: May be an issue on your end. I have no problem opening it.

Comment: Same here. No issues.

Comment: You don't need to open a link to copy it's address! Right click on the link.

Comment: @curiousdannii: You've just taught me something. Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you have problems with is opening [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ep6C7.gif). Is a 4908x4408 px plot GIF image with 1,203.9 KB of data. Your browser either, runs out of memory due a memory leak (that we cannot help, report a bug) or your system is quite tight on resources (we cannot help either).

Answer (score 0):

Like several commenters, I am having no trouble opening that question by clicking its link:

- [Why do the dry and moist adiabatic lapse rates converge with height?](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/4965/why-do-the-dry-and-moist-adiabatic-lapse-rates-converge-with-height)

If you still do then I think you will need to edit your question to include more details about the operating system and browser that you are using to try and access it.